# on change function does not fire on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, function, onchange

I'm trying to improve the checkout at my page. At one point, you can select the delivery date with an `input type="date"` . When the date is changed, the shipping methods should be enabled/disabled, works pretty fine on desktop browsers and android. But the on change function does not fire on iOS

**jQuery** Part

```
function updateDeliveryDay() {
    $('input[name="delivery_date"').on('change', function () {
        //do something
    });
}
```

and the part from the .phtml

```
<input type="date" name="delivery_date" id="delivery_date" min="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" placeholder="-" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

problem solved

```
 function updateDeliveryDay() {
    $(document).on('change', '#delivery_date', function () {
        // do someth
    });
}
```